# N-Toffoli on Cirq

Tags: circuit-construction, cirq

I am looking for guidance in more generally how to developed n-bit gates in Cirq.

I am working on a QNN paper and I need to develop a n-controlled gate to be able to measure the cost function of the circuit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually very easy in Cirq. The `controlled_by` method can be used to automatically make any given gate controlled by an arbitrary number of control qubits. Here is a simple example for creating an X gate with 5 controls:

```
import cirq

qb = [cirq.LineQubit(i) for i in range(6)]

cnX = cirq.X.controlled_by(qb[0], qb[1], qb[2], qb[3], qb[4])

circuit = cirq.Circuit()
circuit.append(cnX(qb[5]))
```

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering though: how can this solution work when you have n-qubits and you cannot hardcode it like the example above?

Comment: Use an unpacking asterisk, e.g. `cnX = cirq.X.controlled_by(*qb[:-1])`

Comment: The specific form in this answer is going to stop working in Cirq v0.6.0, due to some tricky issues around `cnX` knowing some of its qubits but not all. (The meaning of `num_qubits` became ambiguous in ways that led to bugs. E.g. is it the total qubit count or the unspecified qubit count?) But the form `cirq.X(target).controlled_by(*controls)` will still work, and we added `cirq.X.controlled(control_count)`.

Answer (score 0):

For doing CnX (N-CNOT or N-Tofolli) gate,

The following is the correct way to do using `cirq`.

```
from cirq import X, Circuit

NUM_QBITS = 3
qbits = cirq.LineQubit.range(NUM_QBITS)
qa = cirq.NamedQubit("ansilla")

cnX = X.controlled(NUM_QBITS).on(*qbits[:NUM_QBITS], qa)

print(Circuit(cnX))
```

Demo: https://to.absk.im/32QqLku